# Why it insert blank string from ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, sql-insert

```
add_data={"name":$("#name").val(), "smst":$("#smst option:selected").val(), "grade":$("#grade option:selected").val(), "score":$("#score option:selected").val(), "label":$("#label option:selected").val()};

        $.ajax({
            url: "add.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: add_data,
            contentType: 'charset=EUC-KR',
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
```

it's ajax.

```
mysql_select_db("a");
$name=$_POST['name'];
$smst=$_POST['smst'];
$grade=$_POST['grade'];
$score=$_POST['score'];
$label=$_POST['label'];
$query="insert into calcul VALUES ('$name', '$smst','$grade','$score','$label');";
mysql_query($query);
```

it's php mysql

and when ajax excute, insert nothing to DB...
someone help me! X(

Comment: content type should be json..

Comment: Insert query needs fields and values - fields are missing `INSERT INTO calcul (fields) VALUES (values);`. Also, you are using depreciated `mysql` functions and you are vulnerable to injection attack see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: dump $_POST to check if you get the values successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `contentType` to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` or remove it completely, because this is default value.